# What directories/files are actually installed by Ubuntu in the EFI partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have dual booted Windows 11 and Ubuntu 23.04 on my PC, and for some reason I want to backup the EFI partition of the boot disk (C drive). I mounted it, and saw that there are a few directories:

- `boot/`
- `Microsoft/`
- `ubuntu/`

Now I can clearly understand that `ubuntu/` was added here when I installed Ubuntu, and it is the place where the GRUB bootloader resides. But what about the `boot/` directory? Is it also related to the Ubuntu installation?

I'm using a Dell PC.